# How to create an MVC 2 dropdown user control for use in multiple views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to MVC and the new paradigm hasn't clicked yet. I want to create a user control that is a simple dropdown and uses data from a database to populate its items. The dropdown would be useable in any view I chose. At this point I don't need the control to be data/table agnostic, I'd settle for making the user control strongly typed like a view.

The scenario I'm looking at currently is to use the SelectedIndexChanged event (or its equivalent in MVC 2) to populate a table of related data.

Here is the markup from the Home\Index.aspx page for the html helper I'm trying to use.

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("SalesTerritories", new SelectList(MvcAdventure.Models.SalesTerritory, "TerritoryID", "Name")) %>
```

The dropdown helper doesn't work because 'MvcAdventure.Models.SalesTerritory' is invalid in this context (as the runtime told me when it went to render the page).

thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a [Templated Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450.aspx).

It lets you define a bit of markup that you can reuse all over your application, like so:

```
<td>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(Product=> item.SellStartDate, "Date") %> 
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had gotten this far too. The problem I'm having is tying the data into the templated helper. I have an entity model that contains the data I want to use. In a strongly typed view I'd refer to Model.... to get at the data. But since this view isn't strongly typed and I want to display data from multiple tables on it I can't strongly type the view. 

If I wanted to use AdventureWorks.SalesTerritories for the dropdown how do I access the AdventureWorksEntities context to pull the SalesTerritories TerritoryID and Name fields into the dropdown?

Comment: Here is where I'm at on this. In my HomeController.cs Index method

var territories = from st in entities.SalesTerritories select st;
ViewData["SalesTerritories"] = new SelectList(entities.SalesTerritories.ToList(), "TerritoryID", "Name");

In Home\Index.aspx
<%: Html.Partial("SalesTerritoryDropDownViewUserControl")%>

In Views\Shared\SalesTerritoryDropDownViewUserControl.ascx
<%: Html.DropDownList("SalesTerritories")%>

The error I get is: error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SalesTerritories' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcAdventure.Models'

In